# HTMX / Django List Of Forms - CSRF Token Issue?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-csrf, htmx

I've got an application where I'm listing out a bunch of forms - it loads a csrf_token into each form.

Each form is a simple dropdown for choosing a 'color' for each item in the list.

I have a `ListView` that returns a list of placement objects like so:

```
    {% for placement in placements %}
        {% include 'placements/snippets/placement_update_form.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The `placement_update_form.html` looks like this:

```
<form id="placementUpdateForm" action="{{ placement.get_update_url }}" method="post" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ placement.id }}">
    <label for="color">Color</label>
    <select name="color" id="color{{ placement.pk }}" class="form-select" hx-post="{% url 'placements:placement-update' placement.pk %}" hx-target="closest #placementUpdateForm">
        <option value="" {% if not placement.color %}selected{% endif %}>Default</option>
        {% for value, display_name in placement_colors %}
            <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == placement.color %}selected{% endif %}>{{ display_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

I am using HTMX to `POST` the data to an `UpdateView` on my backend; which redirects to a `success_url` that is a `DetailView` that simply returns the `placement_update_template` and replaces that exact item in the DOM.

It works - *once*. The *first* `POST` works and saves the color as expected. The template is replaced in the DOM, but if you choose a different color (triggering a second `POST`) then it fails.

Also, if I try to change the color of any of the *other* forms - it also fails with the same error.

All subsequent `POST` requests are giving me this error:

`Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header incorrect.): /placements/1/update/`

What is the best way to handle this when submitting these forms via HTMX?

Here is a more in-depth breakdown of views/templates/logic: https://pastebin.com/YttsAYZC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue and the easiest way to handle it is to use hx-headers in the following way:

```
<body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
   ...
</body>
```

Ref:
https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#make-htmx-pass-the-csrf-token

Comment: Will that work even if I'm not using the django-htmx library?

Comment: Yes, it will work without it.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue: first submission works fine, second submission (after it re-renders the html template) fails. I made a pastebin with a lot more detailed information: https://pastebin.com/YttsAYZC

Comment: Are you sure you're using the above solution? In your example the token is still embedded inside the form.

Comment: I tried the suggestion (having it in a higher level element - including the body); but it did not resolve the issue for me - mostly because there's a 'base template' that includes another, that includes another, etc. Almost every way I try it, I run into this same issue.

Comment: FWIW: when I include hx-headers in the body element, it doesn't even succeed on the *first* POST. It gives me that error on any/all posts when I include it in the body tag.

Comment: I marked this as 'the answer' as it's the most recommended way of doing things in the event a user cannot use {% csrf_token %} - and because hx-headers is inherited it would allow it to always work. My answer was more complex and I referenced it in the other answers on this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<form id="placementUpdateForm" action="{{ placement.get_update_url }}" method="post" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    <select name="color" id="color{{ placement.pk }}" class="form-select" 
     hx-post="{% url 'placements:placement-update' placement.pk %}"
     hx-target="closest #placementUpdateForm"
     hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    <option value="" {% if not placement.color %}selected{% endif %}>Default</option>
    {% for value, display_name in placement_colors %}
        <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == placement.color %}selected{% endif %}>{{ display_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
```

submit form:

```
<form id="placementUpdateForm" action="{{ placement.get_update_url }}" method="post">
    <!-- hidden inputs for the form submission -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>

or

<form id="placementUpdateForm"
    hx-post="{% url 'math_placements:math-placement-update' placement.pk %}"
    hx-target="#placementUpdateForm"
    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    <!-- hidden inputs for the form submission -->
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue: first submission works fine, second submission (after it re-renders the html template) fails. I made a pastebin with a lot more detailed information: https://pastebin.com/YttsAYZC

Comment: in the console, second submission is a htmx request?

Comment: I started realizing that the session cookie csrf_token was being regenerated on every request (uncommon); after some trial/error I realized some middleware was goofing it up. REMOTE_USER middleware - if I disabled it worked fine. That also lead me to see that using 127.0.0.1 in the URL caused the issue, where using localhost didn't (even with using REMOTE_USER middleware); so I'm using localhost and everything is working as it should now...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this issue, but only after logging in with a different user.  I had my entire body tag wrapped with an hx-boost="true", which included my login form.

Changing my login form to perform a full post, and redirect, fixed my issue.   (hx-boost="false" on the login form directly)

**It appears that logging in to Django's auth, regenerates a new CSRF cookie, and therefore, the body tag does not get the update.**

Switching to a header meta tag, with a javascript event handler may also fixed the problem more cleanly, since you can keep the boosted login form, and let HTMX do the header merge.

Hope this helps!