# Adding CSRF tokens to HTML buttons with HTMX and Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, htmx

I am using Laravel 10 and slowly incorporating HTMX (which I LOVE). I am attempting to add a `data-hx-post` to a button that POSTs to a web route I have defined. I am getting a 419 error. Ok, cool, seen this before- all I have to do is add `@csrf` to the button, right?

That approach worked with forms, but apparently not for buttons. The csrf directive correctly adds a hidden input field to the DOM, but I guess it doesn't get sent with the button POST like it does with forms. Is there a way to add CSRF tokens to native HTML buttons, or do I need to start writing some JavaScript to add the token after button press? I've poked around a few SO questions and that seems to be the most common advice, but I would really like to avoid using JavaScript where I can- that's why I'm using HTMX to handle it all for me :-).

Button code:

```php
<button type="button" class="tailwind stuff" data-hx-post="route">
@csrf
  <span class="tailwind stuff">X</span>
</button>
```

I am not using Laravel Sanctum, this is a SPA with minimal JavaScript (basically all php and HTMX), I'm not using Livewire and I'm not using Alpine.js. I also see no output in my laravel.log file- I'm just receiving a 419 when I click the button. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Buttons as buttons do nothing, and `@csrf` creates an input value with the CSRF token to be used on a form. You're modifying things with the data-hx-post. So you'll need to see how to append CSRF tokens to your htmx request. This is the first I've heard of htmx, so you'll have to do some digging.

Comment: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/70 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956789/htmx-django-list-of-forms-csrf-token-issue might help

Comment: @aynber Thank you for those links, they helped me put a very simple solution in place. I had seen the solution in the [HTMX documentation](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:configRequest), but my aversion to JS kept me from seeing how simple it really was. I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this without js, but this will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let htmx send csrf token value with every request by attaching it to the body element with [hx-headers](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-headers/) attribute:

```
<body hx-headers='{"X-CSRF-TOKEN": "{{ csrf_token() }}"}'>
```

This approach is explained [here in more details](https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#make-htmx-pass-the-csrf-token) (django-htmx docs). It should work same way with laravel, by using the above snippet.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I have no idea why I couldn't find `hx-headers` in the htmx docs, I really scoured it. Thank you!